# Tolerance with Min Max

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to adjust the below code by adding a 2 week tolerance piece.

What it does it looks when the first time a customer (identifier) created a request and the first time it was completed and counts the days which happened in between.

However I am trying to add a tolerance piece. Which says  count the number of NCO which occurred between those dates and if there were further requests past the completion date which happened within 2 weeks of the completion date then count those as well (part of the same request). Anything past 2 weeks of the completions date consider as a new request.

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
(
Identifier varchar(40)NOT NULL
,Created_Date DATETIME NOT NULL
,Completed_Date DATETIME  NULL
,SN_Type varchar(20) NOT NULL
,SN_Status varchar(20) NOT NULL
)
;

INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES ('3333333','2017-02-14 15:00:40.000','2017-02-15 00:00:00.000','Re-Activattion', 'COMP');
INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES ('3333333','2017-05-24 16:41:04.000','2017-06-05 00:00:00.000','Re-Activattion', 'N-CO');
INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES ('3333333','2017-05-25 11:49:54.000','2017-05-26 00:00:00.000','Re-Activattion', 'COMP');
INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES ('3333333','2017-06-27 10:24:29.000',NULL,'Re-Activattion', 'ACC');
```

@Alex you code is accurate just I would like to be selecting the min date the record is created a 2nd time, so line 2 of the result should return min date to be 2017-05-24 16:41:04.000.

```
select identifier
      ,case
          when sum(case when SN_STATUS='COMP' and SN_TYPE = 'Re-Activattion' then 1 else 0 end)>0
          then str(datediff(day
                           ,MIN(case
                                   when SN_TYPE = 'Re-Activattion'
                                   then Created_Date
                                   else null
                                end
                               )
                           ,min(case
                                   when (SN_TYPE = 'Re-Activattion'
                                    and  SN_STATUS='COMP'
                                        )
                                   then Completed_Date
                                   else null
                                end
                               )
                           )
                  )
          when sum(case when SN_TYPE='Re-Activattion' then 1 else 0 end)>0
          then 'NOT COMP'
          else 'NO RE-ACT'
       end
       as RE_ACT_COMPLETION_TIME
         ,Sum(CASE WHEN SN_STATUS = 'N-CO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [RE-AN NCO #]
  from #temp
 group by identifier
;
```

RESULTS I AM AFTER:

[image]

Comment: can you provide a sample data where NCO is not counted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table design is not optimal for these kinds of queries as there is no definitive record that specified order start and order end. Additionally multiple orders are stored with the same identifier.

To work around this you need to calculate/identify Order start and Order End records yourself.

One way to do it is using [Common Table Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql).

**Note:** I have added comments to code to explain what each section does.

```
-- calculate/identify Order start and Order End records
WITH cte AS
(
    -- 1st Order start record i.e. earliest record in the table for a given "Identifier"
    SELECT Identifier, MIN( Created_Date ) AS Created_Date, CONVERT( VARCHAR( 30 ), 'Created' ) AS RecordType, 1 AS OrderNumber
    FROM #temp
    GROUP BY Identifier
    UNION ALL
    -- All records with "COMP" status are treated as order completed events. Add 2 weeks to the completed date to create a "dummy" Order End Date
    SELECT Identifier, DATEADD( WEEK, 2, Created_Date ) AS Created_Date, 'Completed' AS RecordType, ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY Identifier ORDER BY Created_Date ) AS OrderNumber
    FROM #temp
    WHERE SN_STATUS = 'COMP'
    UNION ALL
    -- Set the start period of the next order to be right after (3 ms) the previous Order End Date
    SELECT Identifier, DATEADD( ms, 3, DATEADD( WEEK, 2, Created_Date )) AS Created_Date, 'Created' AS RecordType, ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY Identifier ORDER BY Created_Date ) + 1 AS OrderNumber
    FROM #temp
    WHERE SN_STATUS = 'COMP'
),
-- Combine Start / End records into one record
OrderGroups AS(
    SELECT Identifier, OrderNumber, MIN( Created_Date ) AS OrderRangeStartDate, MAX( Created_Date ) AS OrderRangeEndDate
    FROM cte
    GROUP BY Identifier, OrderNumber
)

SELECT a.Identifier, a.OrderNumber, OrderRangeStartDate, OrderRangeEndDate,
    case
          when sum(case when SN_STATUS='COMP' and SN_TYPE = 'Re-Activattion' then 1 else 0 end)>0
          then str(datediff(day
                           ,MIN(case
                                   when SN_TYPE = 'Re-Activattion'
                                   then Created_Date
                                   else null
                                end
                               )
                           ,min(case
                                   when (SN_TYPE = 'Re-Activattion'
                                    and  SN_STATUS='COMP'
                                        )
                                   then Completed_Date
                                   else null
                                end
                               )
                           )
                  )
          when sum(case when SN_TYPE='Re-Activattion' then 1 else 0 end)>0
          then 'NOT COMP'
          else 'NO RE-ACT'
       end as RE_ACT_COMPLETION_TIME,
    Sum(CASE WHEN SN_STATUS = 'N-CO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [RE-AN NCO #]
FROM OrderGroups AS a
    INNER JOIN #Temp AS b ON a.Identifier = b.Identifier AND a.OrderRangeStartDate <= b.Created_Date AND b.Created_Date <= a.OrderRangeEndDate
GROUP BY a.Identifier, a.OrderNumber, OrderRangeStartDate, OrderRangeEndDate
```

Output:

```
Identifier     OrderNumber   OrderRangeStartDate     OrderRangeEndDate       RE_ACT_COMPLETION_TIME RE-AN NCO #
-------------- ------------- ----------------------- ----------------------- ---------------------- -----------
200895691      1             2016-01-27 14:25:00.000 2016-02-10 15:15:00.000          0             2
200895691      2             2016-02-10 15:15:00.003 2017-01-16 12:15:00.000          1             1
```

Output for the updated data set:

```
Identifier   OrderNumber  OrderRangeStartDate     OrderRangeEndDate       RE_ACT_COMPLETION_TIME RE-AN NCO #
------------ ------------ ----------------------- ----------------------- ---------------------- -----------
200895691    1            2017-01-11 00:00:00.000 2017-03-27 00:00:00.000         61             4
200895691    2            2017-03-27 00:00:00.003 2017-04-20 00:00:00.000          1             1
3333333      1            2017-01-27 00:00:00.000 2017-02-10 00:00:00.000          0             2
44454544     1            2017-01-27 00:00:00.000 2017-01-27 00:00:00.000 NOT COMP               1
7777691      1            2017-02-08 09:36:44.000 2017-02-22 09:36:44.000         63             1
```

## Update 2017-10-05 in response to the comment

Input:

```
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES
('11111','20170203','20170203','Re-Activattion', 'COMP'),
('11111','20170206','20170202','Re-Activattion', 'N-CO');
```

Output:

```
Identifier OrderNumber  OrderRangeStartDate     OrderRangeEndDate       RE_ACT_COMPLETION_TIME RE-AN NCO #
---------- ------------ ----------------------- ----------------------- ---------------------- -----------
11111      1            2017-02-03 00:00:00.000 2017-02-17 00:00:00.000          0             1
```

Comment: Hi Alex. Thanks for giving this a go. I know the data inst ideal and makes it difficult to work with. I tried your code, though for the example I provided it works great I attempted in a few scenarios (see above updated data set) and doesn't quiet fit together. I tired using Islands. got very close but still no cake.

Comment: @Danielle - it looks like I have made a small mistake in my query, I forgot to include Identifier in the `INNER JOIN` condition (the final `SELECT`). Once I have added this condition it returns the "Expected Results" (updated ones). Makes me wonder if people actually try to understand the solution ..... Anyway, I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm. Just one thing I am trying to add whether the first time it was **created** if it was completed the same day or next day.              ---  , CASE WHEN datediff(day, Created_Date, Completed_Date) = 0 THEN 'SAME DAY' ELSE 'NOT SAME DAY' end AS SANE_DAY_FLAG
  , CASE WHEN datediff(day, Created_Date, Completed_Date) = 1 THEN 'NEXT DAY' ELSE 'NOT NEXT DAY' end AS NEXT_DAY_FLAG               ----- Only thing is I dont where in which island to pop it in. Cant seem to get the right result

Comment: @Danielle - start with the final query.

Comment: I just had a look at the below case and the completion time should be 0 but its because it looks from when it was first requested its saying one. is there a way of saying chose the min requested date from the min created date (first time it was created)                                                                  INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES ('11111','20170203','20170203','20170203','Re-Activattion', 'COMP');
INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES ('11111','20170206','20170202',null,'Re-Activattion', 'N-CO');

Comment: @Danielle, I am not quite sure what you mean. I have run the query provided in the answer (as is) with your input (I have removed the 3rd date column as it did not fit your table definition) and got 0. See updated answer.

Comment: Also it would be nice to know if my original answer actually helped solve your problem or not as you have never accepted it.